# The Definition of the Second Fundamental Form

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces

Let $r:M\rightarrow{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}}$ be an isometric immersion and $M$ is an $n$-dimensional Riemannian Manifold. That is to say, $M$ is the hypersurface in $\mathbb{{R}^{n+1}}$.

> Then we can introduce a normal vector field: $N:M\rightarrow{T\mathbb{{R}^{n+1}}}=\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\times{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}}$ satisfies $N_p\in{T_{r(p)}\mathbb{R}^{n+1}}=\{r(p)\}\times\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. So we will have $T_{r(p)}\mathbb{R}^{n+1}=r_*(T_pM)\oplus{span\{N_p\}}$.
>
> Before we talk about this problem, we look at the connection on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Let $\bigtriangledown$ be its connection and $X=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}x_ie_i$, $Y=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}y_ie_i$. So $\bigtriangledown_XY=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}x_je_j(y_i)e_i$.

When I read book, I find two different definitions of **The Second Fundamental Form**. I want to verify that they are the same.

> Let $\bar{n}$ denote the Guass Map which is actually: $n=\pi_2\circ{N}:M\rightarrow{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}}$.
>
> The first definition is:
>
> > $II|_U=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}<\bigtriangledown_{\frac{\partial{r}}{\partial{x_i}}}N,\frac{\partial{r}}{\partial{x_j}}>dx_i\otimes{dx_j}$
>
> The second definition is:
>
> > $II|_U=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}<\frac{\partial{n}}{\partial{x_i}},\frac{\partial{r}}{\partial{x_j}}>dx_i\otimes{dx_j}$

So I think they are the same. Then I try to prove it. But I am failed.

> I want to prove $\bigtriangledown_{\frac{\partial{r}}{\partial{x_i}}}N=\frac{\partial{n}}{\partial{x_i}}$.
>
> > **Proof.** Let $\frac{\partial{r}}{\partial{x_i}}=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{\partial{r_k}}{\partial{x_i}}e_k$ and $N=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}n_ke_k$.
> > Then I have no idea.

How to prove??

Comment: Use **Gauss' equation** in the form $\nabla_XY=D_XY-(D_XY\cdot n)n$ where $D$ is the ${\Bbb{R}}^{n+1}$-standard connection.

Comment: looking at the case of surfaces in ${\Bbb{R}}^3$ will give the clue.

Comment: You use the **Guass's Equation**, so is that to say that one should use the connection's fractionation along tangent space in the inner product in **The Second Fundamental Form**? And could you write down the answer by using the local representation of **The Second Fundmantal Form**? I will be more thankful.@janmarqz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

Consider that if $\langle\partial_j,n\rangle=0$ then also $\langle D_{\partial_i}\partial_j,n\rangle+\langle\partial_j,D_{\partial_i}n\rangle=0$. Use it to correct your guessing.

One is taking $\partial_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ for the coordinated tangent vectors.

**Update:**

Very probable you are using the standard covariant derivative $\nabla$ of ${\Bbb{R}}^{n+1}$.

In this case one computes for $\nabla_XY=[JY]X$ for vector fileds $X,Y$ where $[JY]$ means the 
Jacobian  of the field $Y$.

The covariant derivative and the pairing satisfy:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\langle X,Y\rangle=
\langle \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}}X,Y\rangle
+
\langle X,\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}}Y\rangle
.$$

When applied to $N$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$
which $\langle N,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\rangle=0$ then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\langle N,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\rangle&=&0\\
\langle \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}}N,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\rangle+\langle N,\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\rangle&=&0\\
\langle \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}}N,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\rangle&=&-
\langle N,\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\rangle
\end{eqnarray*}

So 
$$II|_U=\sum_{ij}
\langle\nabla_{\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{x^i}}}N,\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{x^j}}
\rangle dx^i\otimes{dx^j},
$$
is also
$$\qquad
=-\sum_{ij}
\langle N,\nabla_{\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{x^i}}}\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{x^j}}
\rangle dx^i\otimes{dx^j}.
$$

Comment: $\nabla_{\partial_i}n=D_{\partial_i}n$ because $<\partial_i,n>=0$

Comment: meanwhile check the pages 26-27 of http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~yakov/scanlib/hicks.pdf for the form of the Gauss's eqn mentioned

Comment: write briefly $\partial_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$